# Autosort a range of data with Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having some trouble with autosorting my data and i have tried a couple of solutions from here but for some reason i can't seem to make it work.

What i am trying to accomplish is sort a range (A11:BB58), in a particular sheet in a workbook, by the values in Column 2 in descending order.

Perhaps i need to add that the range should autosort after clicking a button in cell A1

Comment: Does the range contain only values, no formulas?  And why not simply through the menu?  There is also Data -> Filter Views

Comment: Sheet.getRange().sort({column:2,ascending:false});

Comment: how do i use this

Answer (score 0):

```
function as() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('sheet name');
  sh.getRange('A11:BB58)').sort({column:2,ascending:false});
}
```